# The application has stopped unexpectedly (Adobe AIR/Android/FlashDevelop)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

EDIT: Turns out my Android device isn't compatible with Adobe AIR :(

I'm trying to build an app with Adobe AIR (using FlashDevelop) to run on my Android device. However, when I and run the APK with goto android-test, on my device, it immediately stops and closes with the message "The application has stopped unexpectedly." Also, when I try to run in debug mode using goto android-debug, I just get a blank black screen.

Here is my main class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.ui.Multitouch;
    import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;


    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivate);

            // touch or gesture?
            Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
        }

        private function deactivate(e:Event):void 
        {
        }

    }

}
```

And here is my application.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/14.0">

    <id>ceronio.net.mobile2</id>
    <versionNumber>0.1</versionNumber>
    <supportedProfiles>mobileDevice</supportedProfiles>
    <filename>mobile2</filename>

    <name>mobile2</name>
    <description></description>
    <copyright></copyright>

    <android>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[

            <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
              <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
                <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>
            </manifest>

        ]]></manifestAdditions>
    </android>
    <iPhone> 
        <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[ 

            <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key> 
            <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string> 
            <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key> 
            <string>NO</string>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>  
            <true/>
            <key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
            <true/>

            <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
            <array>
                <!-- iPhone support -->
                <string>1</string> 
                <!-- iPad support -->
                <!--<string>2</string>-->
            </array>

        ]]></InfoAdditions> 
        <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
    </iPhone> 

    <initialWindow>
        <title>mobile2</title>
        <content>mobile2.swf</content>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
        <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
    </initialWindow>

    <icon>
        <image48x48>icons/icon_48.png</image48x48>
        <image57x57>icons/icon_57.png</image57x57>
        <image72x72>icons/icon_72.png</image72x72>
    </icon>

</application>
```

I'm using Flex 4.6.0 and AIR 14.0 SDKs and FlashDevelop is up to date.

Comment: I don't know much about Android development, but I've done other device development. Is there an error log or console window where you can get more info about the error? Is there a "clean" function you can run before you build or even just delete the previous runtime on the device? Sometimes rewriting to a device clears things up especially if its an error before anything happens.

Comment: With the help of your comment, I've figured it out; my Android device isn't compatible with Adobe AIR :( Looks like I'll have to get an upgrade. Thanks for the help :)